# Splunk query(SPL). Replace a value or anything that comes after the value until a special character

Tags: splunk

I have these values in field from my query.

C360Lookup~single/MainMenu~2/e2_quote_policy_ask_zipcode~90094/e2_quote_existing_policy_utterance~sales_default/e2_quote_existing_policy~_xfer
C360Lookup~single/MainMenu~2/e2_quote_policy_ask_zipcode~94579/e2_quote_existing_policy_utterance~insurance/e2_quote_existing_policy~_xfer
C360Lookup~none/MainMenu~2/e2_quote_policy_ask_zipcode~91748/e2_quote_existing_policy_utterance~insurance.utterance.contains(quote)/e2_quote_existing_policy~_xfer

I want e2_quote_policy_ask_zipcode* to be replaced by AskZipcode. The output should like  below in

C360Lookup~single/MainMenu~2/AskZipcode/e2_quote_existing_policy_utterance~sales_default/e2_quote_existing_policy~_xfer
C360Lookup~single/MainMenu~2/AskZipcode/e2_quote_existing_policy_utterance~insurance/e2_quote_existing_policy~_xfer
C360Lookup~none/MainMenu~2/AskZipcode/e2_quote_existing_policy_utterance~insurance.utterance.contains(quote)/e2_quote_existing_policy~_xfer

I tried multiple ways. Not able to achieve the desired results

Comment: what have you tried? You say you have "tried multiple ways" - but we need elucidation to know how to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for the `rex` command.  Use the `sed` (Stream EDitor) option to replace text in a field.

```
| rex mode=sed field=foo "s/e2_quote_policy_ask_zipcode[^\/]+?/AskZipcode/g"
```

Comment: It works partially. It also removes the rest of the field value. The output looks like this now.
C360Lookup~single/MainMenu~2/AskZipcode

Comment: Perhaps my regex was too greedy.  Please try the updated command.

Comment: The updated query works almost. It was still missing the numbers. The below worked. thank you for letting me know about sed mode.

replace(foo, "e2_quote_policy_ask_zipcode~\d{4}[^/]+?", "AskZipcode")

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`eval replace()`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/eval)

It's still regex based, but simpler to understand (and, often, faster to run) than [`rex mode=sed`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex):

```
| eval myfield=replace(myfield,"e2_quote_policy_ask_zipcode[^\/]+","AskZipcode")
```